# build ros on mac Rviz error 'qregularexpression.h' file not found'

Tags: ros, rviz, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the error is "  'qregularexpression.h' file not found'
but I can find the file in /usr/local/Cellar/qt/5.8.0_2/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/Headers/qregularexpression.h

I have googled this question but can`t find any proper answer...

```
In file included from tool_manager.sip:8:
In file included from /Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/rviz/tool_manager.h:36:
In file included from /Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/src/rviz/src/rviz/pluginlib_factory.h:40:
In file included from /Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/pluginlib/class_loader.h:33:
/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/include/class_loader/multi_library_class_loader.h:106:7: warning: 'log_deprecated' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
      logDebug("class_loader::MultiLibraryClassLoader: Attempting to create instance of class type %s.", class_name.c_str());
      ^
/usr/local/Cellar/console_bridge/0.3.2/include/console_bridge/console.h:99:19: note: expanded from macro 'logDebug'
  console_bridge::log_deprecated(__FILE__, __LINE__, console_bridge::CONSOLE_BRIDGE_LOG_DEBUG, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
                  ^
/usr/local/Cellar/console_bridge/0.3.2/include/console_bridge/console.h:202:54: note: 'log_deprecated' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
CONSOLE_BRIDGE_DEPRECATED CONSOLE_BRIDGE_DLLAPI void log_deprecated(const char *file, int line, LogLevel level, const char* m, ...);
                                                     ^
/usr/local/share/sip/PyQt5/QtCore/qregularexpression.sip:26:10: fatal error: 'qregularexpression.h' file not found
#include <qregularexpression.h>
         ^
12 warnings and 1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [siplibrviz_siprvizToolManager.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [/Users/baidu/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rviz/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rviz/librviz_sip.dylib] Error 2
make[1]: *** [src/python_bindings/sip/CMakeFiles/librviz_sip.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262357/build-ros-on-mac-rviz-error----%27qregularexpression.h%27-file-not-found%27/) by [westeast](https://answers.ros.org/users/30354/westeast/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2017-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solve this problem by rm qt@4

---

Originally posted by [westeast](https://answers.ros.org/users/30354/westeast/) with karma: 51 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0